# Xampp Hosting multiple applications

Tags: php, apache, xampp, hosting

I am running XAMPP on NUC i7 windows 10 pro. Its IP address is a.b.c.d and has 4 applications in the htdocs folder named app1 (html5 + php form), app2 (drupal 7 based site), app3 (html5 site).
I don't know how it is automatically re routing the traffic to these individual apps by just typing this on any device connected to the same network:

> http://a.b.c.d/app1
>
> http://a.b.c.d/app2
>
> http://a.b.c.d/app3

Problem comes when I am adding another folder app4 for my wordpress installation. When I am on this machine locally, I can access the wordpress site by localhost/app4 but cannot access it from other clients on the network by typing http://a.b.c.d/app4
My browser converts the ip address into localhost/app4 which doesn't exist on my client machine.

I've modified my httpd.conf as:

```
#Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

updated httpd-vhosts.conf file like:

```
NameVirtualHosts *:80    
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/app4"
        ServerName app4.localhost
        ServerAlias www.dummy-host.localhost
        ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-error.log"
        CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-access.log" combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

and added entries in my host file as

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   app1
127.0.0.1   app2
127.0.0.1   app3
127.0.0.1   app4
127.0.0.1   app5
```

I've tried other examples googling around but nothing seems to be working. Even tried other SO examples like [SO Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660066/hosting-multiple-local-sites-with-xampp) and [other SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051731/xampp-hosting-multiple-sites)

Am I heading in the wrong direction?

Comment: Did you try restarting Xampp after making the vHost change?

Comment: yup. restarted xampp after every update/change to conf files.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is likely redirecting http://a.b.c.d/app4 to http://localhost/app4

Change the site url and site name in the wordpress install to app4.

It may also help you to do a hard reload or open in an incognito window (if you're using chrome) as a 301 redirect would be stored by the browser.